# Is it possible to write to other file descriptors in C?

Tags: c, file-descriptors

If I wish to redirect all stdout to a file, I would run

```
my_prog 1> out
```

If I wish to do the same for stderr, I would run

```
my_prog 2> err
```

However, I know that in shell there are other file descriptors as well.  For example, the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460186/writing-outputs-to-log-file-and-console) uses a third file descriptor, to which one can send data from the command line via

```
echo "Some console message" 1>&3
```

Is there a way for a C program to write to this file descriptor?  Does writing to it while no other program is reading it, send its output to the Terminal as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not really familiar with C so there may be better ways to to this but you can simply use the syscall (`man 2 write`):

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

Where the written data is sent depends on what the file desciptor has opened. The data reaches the terminal only if the file descriptor belongs to a terminal.

If you write to a pipeline or socket and the other side doesn't read the data then the writing application (i.e. the `write()` call) will block when the buffers are full.

You can see the file descriptors in `/proc/$PID/fd`

Comment: No directory `/proc` on a Mac.

Answer (score 9):

To clarify a few more things. In:

```
echo foo >&3
```

`echo` is not writing `"foo\n"` to its file descriptor 3. `echo` is always writing to stdout, to its file descriptor 1. It's calling the `write()` system call with a `1` integer as its first argument, a pointer to an area in memory that starts with `foo\n` as the second argument and `4` (the length of `foo\n`) as the third.

In C, you'd write it `write(1, "foo\n", 4)`. In the code above, the shell redirects the fd 1 to the same *open file description* as open on fd 3 before calling `echo` (by way of the `dup2()` system call). So, even though it's functionally equivalent, it's not the same as doing `write(3, "foo\n", 4)`. In effect, it's something like (simplified):

```
if (pid = fork())
  waitpid(pid, ...);
else {
  dup2(3, 1);
  execlp("echo", "foo", 0);
}
```

And `echo` does a `write(1, "foo\n", 4)`

Except that in virtually all shells, `echo` is builtin, so there's no `fork` or `exec`. Instead, the shell does:

```
saved_stdout = dup(1);
dup2(3, 1);
builtin_echo("foo");
dup2(saved_stdout, 1); close(saved_stdout); /* restore stdout */
```

(where `builtin_echo()` is a function that does the `write(1, "foo\n", 4)` in the same process).

For a command that does `write(3, "foo\n", 4)`, you can have a look at `ksh`/`zsh`'s `print -u3 foo` builtin command.

Now, every process is free to use file descriptors as they please. Except that 0, 1 and 2 are by convention reserved for stdin, stdout and stderr. Other fds are generally not special, but in shells (which are just one type of application), fds 0 to `<some-value>` where some value is at least 9 are reserved for usage by the user (of the shell). The shell will not mingle with them for its own internal soup. For instance my `saved_stdout = dup(1)` above was an approximation. In effect, the shell will make sure `saved_stdout` will be a value greater than `<some-value>`.

Now, since there's no convention attached to fds outside 0,1,2, you can't expect anything to be open on fd 3. Most likely it will be closed. Or if it's not, it's likely the caller of your script will just have forgotten to close it (or to add the `O_CLOEXC` flag to it) as there would be no reason it left it open for you as nobody expects anything to be open on fd 3.

You would use the fd 3 if you knew it had been open onto something, generally by you in the same script beforehand, like in:

```
 {
   var=$(cmd 2>&1 >&3)
 } 3>&1
```

Where fd 3 had been defined as a `dup()` of fd 1 *before* we use it for `cmd` to `dup()` it back onto fd 1.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the descriptor is open, C can indeed `write` (or more likely use some higher-level call that will eventually boil down to a `write(2)`) to that descriptor. This here be `write2three.c`

```
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = dup(3)) == -1) err(1, "dup failed");
    dprintf(fd, "hello\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

E.g.

```
$ make write2three  
cc     write2three.c   -o write2three
$ ./write2three
write2three: dup failed: Bad file descriptor
$ rm out
$ ./write2three 3>out
$ cat out
hello
$
```

You may need to clean up in the shell, afterwards.

```
$ exec 3>&-
$
```

Comment: +1: This answers the question of how to make writing to a different file descriptor work together with a variant of `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write to other file descriptors in C?

Yes.

Most processes inherit 3 open file descriptors from the parent that executed them.

`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. These are file descriptors  0 - 2 respectively.

I believe fd 0 (`stdin`) is opened in read only mode, so your c program can read this file descriptor but not write to it.

When you program opens another file, it gets the next file descriptor in incremental order.

Comment: But then writing to the file descriptor this way would write to the file, instead of writing to the process expecting input in the form `echo "Some console message" 1>&3`

Comment: Your example is not `c`, that is a `shell` command. `stdin` is not the 'file', it is usually attached to the controlling terminal.